# Modifying/Correcting Incorrect Year in R

Tags: r, date, tidyverse, purrr, lubridate

I have a dataframe which has some erroneous rows where the year is incorrect.
Is there a way to elegantly change a specific year that I know is incorrect ("2017") to the correct year ("2019").

Example Data:

| Date | Traffic |
| --- | --- |
| 2019/01/01 | 500 |
| 2019/01/02 | 300 |
| 2019/01/03 | 200 |
| 2017/01/04 | 600 |

The Date is in lubridate format and I'm wanting to do something similar such as what you can do with just a single record.

```
year(Date) = 2019
```

which works for a single day but not the entire data frame and only the erroneous records.

I have also tried but obviously this doesn't work:

```
year(ped_2019$Date[year(ped_2019$Date) == 2017]) = "2019"
```

Maybe somehow I could use the map function and year(Date)?

Apologies this is only my second question so still getting used to the format.

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
library(lubridate)

df$Date <- ymd(df$Date)
year(df$Date[year(df$Date) == 2017]) <- 2019
df

#        Date Traffic
#1 2019-01-01     500
#2 2019-01-02     300
#3 2019-01-03     200
#4 2019-01-04     600
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("2019/01/01", "2019/01/02", "2019/01/03", 
"2017/01/04"), Traffic = c(500L, 300L, 200L, 600L)), 
row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Ronak and I can't believe all that needed to change was make it an integer!

Answer (score 1):

An only `dplyr` way using `gsub` could be:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(Date = gsub("2017", "2019", Date))
```

Output:

```
        Date Traffic
1 2019/01/01     500
2 2019/01/02     300
3 2019/01/03     200
4 2019/01/04     600
```

**OR:**

Another way could be using `separate` and `make_date` function:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    separate(Date, c("year", "month", "day"), sep = "/") %>% 
    mutate(year = ifelse(year == 2017, 2019, year)) %>% 
    mutate(Date = make_date(year, month, day), .keep="unused", .before=1
```

output:

```
        Date Traffic
1 2019-01-01     500
2 2019-01-02     300
3 2019-01-03     200
4 2019-01-04     600
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(Date = str_replace(Date, '2017', '2019'))
```

-output

```
      Date Traffic
1 2019/01/01     500
2 2019/01/02     300
3 2019/01/03     200
4 2019/01/04     600
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("2019/01/01", "2019/01/02", "2019/01/03", 
"2017/01/04"), Traffic = c(500L, 300L, 200L, 600L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```